# How to load manual font from manfnt?

Tags: symbols

In the TeXBook, it says that:

`{\manual\char127}` prints the *dangerous bend glyph*.
But it doesn't.

I can do it with `\manfntsymbol{127}`, but how can I switch to the `manfnt` font?

`\font{manfnt}` doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see in `manmac.tex` how it's loaded: give the following declaration at the beginning of your file

```
\font\manual=manfnt
```

and then

```
{\manual\char127}
```

will work.

With LaTeX one can use the `manfnt` characters with

```
\usepackage{manfnt}
```

and `\manfntsymbol{127}`. The package provides also symbolic names that can be found in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), which is also available in TeX Live with `texdoc symbols` (from the command line). For example, the dangerous bend symbol can be typeset with `\dbend`.

Comment: I've loaded font with `\usepackage{manfnt}`

Comment: Your tag said "plain-tex".

Comment: @outmind: You could use `\newcommand*{\manual}{\fontencoding {U}\fontfamily {manual}\selectfont}` I think. The `\manfntsymbol` uses this internally to switch to the correct font.

Comment: @Martin: the **manfnt** package already provides names for the various symbols.