# How to mix accents from different fonts?

Tags: accents

In TeXBook, exercise 9.6 Knuth asks to type Pal Erdos with needed accents in `\tt` font.

So I've tried the naive `{\tt P\'al Erd\H os}` and succeed.
But Knuth proposes to use the next mixup of fonts:

`{\tt P\'al Erd{\bf\H{\tt o}}s}`

It seems like an interesting technique, as it allows to catch accents from other fonts.
But it strange that the code was not succeed, as I received accent `\H` and `o` separate from eacha other. It seems like they were not bound.

How to apply Knuth's technique?

Comment: You shouldn't tag your questions with "plain-tex" when they involve LaTeX.

Comment: @egreg -- where does the question say anything about latex?  since a texbook exercise is cited explicitly, i believe the poster's tagging of "plain-tex" was justified.  for a plain tex answer, i believe this can be done with some `\expandafter`s, but i have to experiment first to figure out how many and where.

Comment: @barbara There is at least [one other message](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22632/how-to-load-manual-font-from-manfnt) by the OP that has the same problem. Since the present code works perfectly in Plain TeX, the only cause for failure is its use in LaTeX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The commands `\tt` and `\bf` shouldn't be used in LaTeX any more, they are present only for back compatibility.

The following input works without any special trick

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\texttt{P\'al Erd\H{o}s}
\end{document}
```

since T1 encoded fonts are used, which have a richer supply of accents and accented characters than OT1 encoded fonts.

Implementing the trick is more complicated in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\texttt{Erd\textnormal{\textbf{\H{\mdseries\ttfamily o}}}s}

\end{document}
```

We first need to call normal font, then boldface for the accent, and return to `\ttfamily` in medium series for the accentee.

[image]

For comparison, here is the plain TeX version

```
{\tt Erd{\bf\H{\tt o}}s}
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: egreg: Thanks egreg. How to mix accents from different fonts in LaTeX?