# How to mix accents from different fonts in LaTeX?

Tags: accents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to mix accents from different fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22704/how-to-mix-accents-from-different-fonts)

In TeXBook, exercise 9.6 Knuth asks to type Pal Erdos with needed accents in `\tt` font.

The answer from the key is `{\tt P\'al Erd{\bf\H{\tt o}}s}`.

However this technique doesn't work in LaTeX. How to apply this to LaTeX?

Comment: Also note that this might not be required for LaTeX at all. Simply load a modern font. Try `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}`. The `\H` macro is defined differently by plainTeX and LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{\ttfamily P\'al Erd{\normalfont\bfseries\H{\ttfamily o}}s}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, egreg! This works! It's exactly what I've looked for.

Comment: However could you please comment the difference? And the problem with the former?

Comment: It works well with the "new" font selection commands, but it won't with the obsolete ones.