# What follows the `^^` in TeX? Hex or Dec or symbol?

Tags: symbols, tex-core, characters, ascii

`^^6\bye` will produces `v`. I can understand this. `6` is the symbol of ASCII table, and the DEC of `6` symbol is 54. As 54 is smaller than 64, so 54+64=128. The 128th symbol of ASCII table is `v`.

`^^61` produces `a`. But from ASCII table, there is no symbol as `61`. Actually, `61` is a Hex code. Its Dec code is 97, the 97th symbol of ASCII is `a`. It is weird. 1. 61 doesn't need to add 64. 2.61 is Hex code not symbol of ASCII table.

The 90th symbol of ASCII table is `Z`. To get the `Z`, 90-64=26, and the 26th symbol of ASCII table is `SUB`. So, `^^SUB` should procude `Z`, but it doesn't. Why?

How to understand the part follows the `^^` in TeX?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149936/discussion-on-question-by-y-zeng-what-follows-the-in-tex-hex-or-dec-or-sy); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two competing `^^` conventions. The original one, valid for TeX version 2, is that TeX looks for the next character code and either adds or subtract 64:

1. if the next character code is greater than or equal to 64, TeX will subtract;
2. if the next character code is less than 64, TeX will add.

In either case, a character code in the range 0–127 is obtained.

However, there's also another convention, introduced in TeX version 3, which can conflict with the previous one in some case, but ***has precedence*** over it.

When the next character, say `x` is among `0123456789abcdef`, TeX will also look at the next character, say `y` and, if again among the same set, the pair of characters is considered as a hexadecimal number and `^^xy` refers to the character with character code `xy` in hexadecimal notation.

Let's make some examples:

```
^^1q
```

would use the original convention; since the character code of `1` is 49, we end up with character number 113 and you get the same as if you input

```
qq
```

To the contrary, the input

```
^^11
```

would follow the version 3 convention and you get the character with code `"11` in hexadecimal, so 17 in decimal, which you can also input as

```
^^Q
```

In your case `^^61` fits in the version 3 convention, which has precedence over the original one, so you get character with code 97 in decimal, as you discovered.

Don't be misled by the table on page 367, where the nonprintable ASCII characters are mentioned by their traditional name, but these names cannot be used like you seem to believe. So `^^SUB` only produces the character with ASCII code `"13` in hexadecimal, so 19 in decimal, followed by the characters `UB`.

Comment: 1. `^^11` equals `^^Q`? No, `^^11` produces `'` but `^^Q` produces `J`, and they both don't obey the original convenrion. 2. `^^S` produces the same result as `^^11`. You can try it.

Comment: @Y.zeng Nope: `^^Q ^^11 \bye` gives two identical characters, while `^^Q ^^11 ^^S \bye` gives two identical characters then one different one, exactly as Enrico says

Comment: @JosephWright  Yes. I was wrong. He is right.

Answer (score 6):

This is explained in the TeXBook

```
\danger \TeX\ has a standard way to refer to the invisible characters of ASCII:
Code~0 can be typed as the sequence of three characters |^^@|, code~1 can
be typed |^^A|, and so on up to code~31, which is |^^_| (see Appendix~C\null).
If the character following |^^| has an internal code between 64 and 127, \TeX\
subtracts 64 from the code; if the code is between 0 and 63, \TeX\
adds~64. Hence code 127 can be typed |^^?|, and
the dangerous bend sign can be obtained by saying
|{\manual^^?}|. However, you must change the category code of character
127 before using it, since this character ordinarily has category~15
(^{invalid}); say, e.g., |\catcode`\^^?=12|.
^^{double hat} ^^{hat hat}
The |^^| notation is different from |\char|, because |^^| combinations are
like single characters; for example, it would not be permissible to say
|\catcode`\char127|, but |^^| symbols can even be used as letters within
control words.

...

\danger There's also a special convention in which |^^| is
followed by {\sl two\/} ``lowercase hexadecimal digits,'' |0|--|9| or |a|--|f|.
With this convention, all 256 characters are obtainable in a uniform
way, from |^^00| to |^^ff|. Character 127 is |^^7f|.
```

so

`^^6`  is like inputting character 54+64 = 118  `v`

`^^61` is two hex digits so is like inputting character hex 61 which is `a`

`^^S` is like inputting character 83-64=19 which is the same as ctrl-s from a keyboard.  Character 19 in the cmr font encoding (known as OT1 in latex) is an acute accent.

```
1 ^^6

2 ^^61

3 ^^S

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149940/discussion-on-answer-by-david-carlisle-what-follows-the-in-tex-hex-or-dec); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.